# Spring: create LocalDate or LocalDateTime from @Value parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In a spring project, I'd like to create a `LocalDate` from an `@Autowired` constructor parameter whose value is in a `.properties` file. Two things I'd like to do:

**1.** If the property file contains the property `my.date`, the parameter should be created by parsing the property value

When the property is set, and when I use the following:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") @Value("${my.date}") LocalDate myDate,
...
```

I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I have also used the `iso = ...` to use an ISO date with the same result.

**2.** If the property is not in the properties file, the parameter should be created using `LocalDate.now()`

I tried using a default value as such:

```
@Value("${my.date:#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}}") LocalDate myDate,
...
```

But I get the same error.

Forgive my ignorance with Spring, but how can I achieve the two objectives here?

Answer (score 24):

I know two ways. One is generic for any object - to use @Value annotation on custom setter

```
@Component
public class Example {

    private LocalDate localDate;

    @Value("${property.name}")
    private void setLocalDate(String localDateStr) {
        if (localDateStr != null && !localDateStr.isEmpty()) {
            localDate = LocalDate.parse(localDateStr);
        }
    }
}
```

The second is for LocalDate/LocalDateTime

```
public class Example {
    @Value("#{T(java.time.LocalDate).parse('${property.name}')}")
    private LocalDate localDate;
}
```

Sample property:

```
property.name=2018-06-20
```

Comment: The second solution errors when the date is null. Is there a solution?

Comment: @Hackerman set a default value:

@Value("#{T(java.time.LocalDate).parse('${property.name:2018-06-20}')}")
 private LocalDate localDate;

Answer (score 14):

Spring Boot 2.5, works perfect:

`application.yaml`

```
my.date: 2021-08-14
my.time: "11:00"
```

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Value("${my.date}")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    LocalDate myDate;

    @Value("${my.time}")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    LocalTime myTime;
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to point out the two possible options to specify the pattern, but obviously, we can also use the `DateTimeFormat.ISO` constant for the LocalDate, like `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the date format as well then use following on the field:

```
@Value("#{T(java.time.LocalDate).parse('${date.from.properties.file}', T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('${date.format.from.properties.file}'))}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this into your properties file:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
```

and remove `@DateTimeFormat` annotation

Concerning LocalDate.now() initialization. Try to use field injection this way:

```
@Value("${my.date}") LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.now();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of initializing a `LocalDateTime` value using annotations and configuration properties. I've tested that it works in Spring Boot 2.4.

MyComponent.kt fragment:

```
@Value("\${my.date}")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
val myDate: LocalDateTime
```

application.yml:

```yaml
my:
  date: "2023-01-23T00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer by Pavel there are two ways.

I am providing similar two ways with modification to handle 2nd Point by OP.

> If the property is not in the properties file, the parameter should be
>   created using LocalDate.now()

```
@Component
public class Example {

private LocalDate localDate;

@Value("${property.name}")
private void setLocalDate(String localDateStr) {
    if (localDateStr != null && !localDateStr.isEmpty()) {
        localDate = LocalDate.parse(localDateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }else{
        localDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
}
}
```

I Prefere 2nd way though...

```
public class Example {
    @Value("#{T(java.time.LocalDate).parse('${property.name}', T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd')) ?: T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}")
    private LocalDate localDate;
}
```

Edit:- Fixed 2nd Way

```
@Value("#{ !('${date:}'.equals('')) ? T(java.time.LocalDate).parse('${date:}', T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('MM-dd-yyyy')) " +
        ":T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}")
private LocalDate asOfDate;
```

Comment: When I try the above I get:

IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'startDate' in value "#{T(java.time.LocalDateTime).parse('${startDate}', T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) ?: T(java.time.LocalDateTime).now()}"

thoughts?

Comment: @JimM.  Fixed the answer... please check.

Answer (score 0):

For the first bit, you could create a converter:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

  @Override
  public LocalDate convert(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return LocalDate.parse(s);
  }
}
```

Your config Class will automatically use this for conversion.

For the 2nd you can just do:

```
if(my.date == null) iso = LocalDate.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case @DateTimeFormat annotation did not work, so to configure ISO format once and for all, I configure the following Bean in an @Configuration class

````java
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar dateTimeFormatterRegistrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    dateTimeFormatterRegistrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
    dateTimeFormatterRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    return conversionService;
}```
````