# Parse LocalTime using spring expression language from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-time, application.properties

I am trying to parse LocalTime from spring's application.properties with following code:

```
@Value("#{ T(java.time.LocalTime).parse('${app.myDateTime}')}")
private LocalTime myDateTime;
```

in application.properties I have defined property like this:

```
app.myDateTime=21:45:00
```

Error message:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'app.my-date-time' to java.time.LocalTime:

Property: app.my-date-time
Value: 21:45:00
Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:44:15
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value java.time.LocalTime
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Thank you.

Error in debug mode:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalTime] for value '21:45:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [21:45:00]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$CompositeConversionService.convert(BindConverter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:258)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:214)
    ... 210 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [21:45:00]
    at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService$ParserConverter.convert(FormattingConversionService.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 217 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '21:45:00' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
    at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:72)
    at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:46)
    at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService$ParserConverter.convert(FormattingConversionService.java:200)
    ... 218 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You need to add complete error message with stack trace

Comment: @Deadpool unfortunately it is. Application failed to start with reason which I write in question. :/

Comment: enable debug level logging and re run the application and also i'm wondering about this `app.my-date-time` property

Comment: @Deadpool I updated question with stack trace, please check it out

Comment: try my answer which is working for me

Answer (score 15):

By default, [Spring uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/39536acf9f28ddcae59bf89ae2c31b8e6a615494/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeFormatterRegistrar.java#L215) localized non-iso `FormatStyle.SHORT` for time formatting unless this is overridden somehow. So I suspect you could use `09:45 PM` for the property value but this is not what you want.

But as I already mentioned, you can just globally override the pattern which is expected by Spring using the [DateTimeFormatterRegistrar](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat) machinery.

Or you can also use the [@DateTimeFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation on your `LocalTime myDateTime` field. With this annotation, there are three ways you can specify the desired format, namely `style`, `iso`, `pattern`. In your situation, `iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME` would work. So your code will look like this:

```
@Value("${app.myDateTime}")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalTime myDateTime;
```

And note, these three attributes are mutually exclusive (see javadoc at the link provided):

> Each attribute is mutually exclusive, so only set one attribute per annotation instance

Answer (score 11):

## Option 1 - use `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding`

If you use `@ConfigurationProperties` to load your properties you can use `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding` to bind custom converters to Spring:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class LocalTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalTime> {
  @Override
  public LocalTime convert(String source) {
      if(source==null){
          return null;
      }
      return LocalTime.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

[image]

## Option 2 - use `@Value`

If you rather stick to `@Value` then you were pretty close:

```
@Value("#{T(java.time.LocalTime).parse('${app.myDateTime}', T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('HH:mm:ss'))}")
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html for a list of DateTimeFormatter options.

Sources:

- [Spring: create LocalDate or LocalDateTime from @Value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575426/spring-create-localdate-or-localdatetime-from-value-parameter)
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/custom-configuration-properties-binding.html

Comment: Second option is what I am looking for but I got same error with that:
failed to convert java.lang.String to @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value java.time.LocalTime

Comment: @DenisStephanov I was surprised to hear that, so I tried the first option myself.  It does work.  The only mistake in that answer is that you want "HH:mm:ss" so that you can parse hours in interval [0-23].  I updated the answer with the hour correction and a screenshot of how it looks like for me. Probably the second answer fails for the same reason.  I linked the DateTimeFormatter documentation with the intention of you suiting the DateTimeFormatter to your needs.

Comment: I updated question with stack trace, please check it out

Comment: Both options work like a charm, this answer should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

To inject Dates into @Value, Spring Expression Language (SpEL) is used, 
for example:

```
@Value(“#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(‘${aTimeFormat}’).parse(‘${aTimeStr}’)}”)
Date myDate;
```

In your case, you are directly injecting the Date value without providing the formatter, so it doesn't knows what format to parse to , define a new property with the format and use that formatter to parse the value like above example, it will get injected.
Your application.properties properties should be like:

```
aTimeStr=21:16:46
aTimeFormat=HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Does this work with `LocalTime`? Because the OP is using `LocalTime`.

Comment: I tried with DateTimeFormatter like this  (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('HH:mm:ss') but not works. Error:
Cannot convert value of type 'java.time.format.Parsed' to required type 'java.time.LocalTime': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on spring boot-2.1.5 with jdk-11

```
@Value("#{ T(java.time.LocalTime).parse('${app.myDateTime}',T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ISO_LOCAL_TIME)}")
private LocalTime timeValue;   //21:45
```

Comment: I don't understant ... same error with this :/ I am using open jdk 8, can be this issue?

Comment: you might make some minute mistakes, or can you try upgrading java version ? @DenisStephanov