# Generate LocalDateTime in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application.

I need to generate `LocalDateTime.now` value in application properties.

I think there should be function like `${random.int}` which generates random value

Comment: What's the use case? Why doing it in java doesn't suffice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse LocalTime using spring expression language from application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526465/parse-localtime-using-spring-expression-language-from-application-properties)

Comment: @RobEvans this is not the same

Comment: The use case is to add to actuator as a custom info

Comment: Do you want time at which application started or built, in actuator or just the current time?

Comment: current time, but from properties, not from java code