# How to resolve placeholder in properties file with values from another properties file in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, properties-file, property-placeholder

My spring boot application has below properties files.

```
src/main/resources/config/DEV/env.properties
mail.server=dev.mail.domain

src/main/resources/config/QA/env.properties
mail.server=qa.mail.domain

src/main/resources/config/common/env.properties
mail.url=${mail.server}/endpoint
```

Is it possible to load "common/env.properties" so that it's placeholders will be resolved using the given environment specific properties file. For DEV environment, we want the placeholders in "common/env.properties" to be resolved using values from "DEV/env.properties".

There are answers about how to load multiple properties files and profile based loading but could not find an answer for this particular use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly what the `application.properties` and profile system are for.

Answer (score 3):

2 Options :

1. Generate the `common/application.properties` using `configuration-maven-plugin` and filter files for each environment. It is outdated now.
2. Use `application-<env>.properties` for each environment and pass the `-Dspring.profiles.active=<env>` as VM option in application start up. Spring will automatically take the property from correct file.

In option 2, you will be overwriting whatever is present in application.properties with application-.properties. So you dont have to add only the properties which you need to change per environment.

for eg:

Your `application.properties` can have

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.apache=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
```

Your `application-dev.properties` can have

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

which means, when you are starting application using `dev` profile, spring takes

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.apache=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

edit :

Also, you can try something like below on your class. (Spring will overwrite value in config.properties with values from config-dev.properties). `ignoreResourceNotFound` will make sure, application will still start with default values even if the corresponding file is not found.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and update. Checking out of curiosity, Is there any way to use /common/env.properties instead of application.properties to store default values.

Comment: You can add the env.properties files to class path. Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499306/how-to-read-application-properties-file-without-environment-variable/50951259#50951259

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by declaring a property source on a class configuration and setting up an environment variable in the path :

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:config/${env}/env.properties" })
@Configuration
public class config{}
```

And then you launch the spring boot app with the command line variable `-env=dev`

**UPDATE**

You can use @PropertySources annotation to load several properties.

```
 @PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:config/${env}/env.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:config/common/env.properties")
  })
  public class config{}
```

Comment: Thanks. How will /common/env.properties be loaded? We would need both /common/env.properties and {env}/env.properties loaded.

Comment: Please see my update in the answer. You can load several properties using `@PropertySources` annotation. So you can load both /common/env.properties and {env}/env.properties at the same time. If it was helpful, thanks to mark the answer as response.

Comment: Thanks, if we load this way, will placeholders in /common/env.properties be resolved with values from {env}/env.properties?

Comment: as there is no placeholders in this path /common/env.properties, there is no resolution.

Comment: Not in the path, but there are placeholders in the content of /common/env.properties. For example; mail.url=${mail.server}/endpoint. We need ${mail.server} be resolved with value from the content of {env}/env.properties. /DEV/env.properties contains mail.server=dev.mail.domain

Answer (score 0):

You can add resources/application.yml file where you can have multiple profiles in one File.
[MultiProfile Yaml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml)
e.g.here are two different profiles 'dev' and 'qa' with different applicationNames 'DEV' and 'QA' and one defaultName 'Default'

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Default
  profiles:
    active: qa

---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  application:
    name: DEV
---
spring:
  profiles: qa
  application:
    name: QA
```