# How to read application.properties into strongly typed class in Java?

Tags: java

Problem: I need to read `application.properties` into a strongly typed class. E.g., I have written a class:

```
public class Config {
  public int param1;
  public boolean param2;
  public String param3;
  public MyEnum param4;
}
```

I would like to know how I can read `application.properties` and get an instance of `Config` whose fields are populated accordingly. The library should allow me to:

- Specify via annotation the property name a `param` maps to in `.properties` file
- Set validation rules on the fields. E.g., `param1` should be between 1 and 100 etc.
- The library should also support passing params through command line `System.properties` (`-D` flag) or through environment variables.
- If a parameter is specified via more than 1 mechanism, the order of precedence is `System.properties` followed by `System.getenv` followed by `.properties` files

Another class should then be able to use this config. E.g.:

```
public class App {
   Config config;

   public void main() {
      // use config here or I am willing to have a statement like:
      // config = loadConfig(); 
      // that will load the config
   }
}
```

There are some questions on this topic but I could not find any **complete** solution that shows:

1. what dependencies I need to add in `pom.xml`
2. What classes I need to import
3. Next steps

and that is updated to current. When I tried to use some of the solutions presented, I got stuck sometimes due to 1 and 2 and at other times the fields in `Config` were not getting initialized.

I am trying to avoid to manually parse `application.properties` and would like to use a library for this complex task. Something like [this](https://github.com/spf13/viper) but for Java.

Comment: Try the following tutorials, _[Properties (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > The Platform Environment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)_. and _[Serializable Objects (The Java™ Tutorials > Java Naming and Directory Interface > Java Objects in the Directory)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)_.

Comment: The Spring framework should already provide this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will depend on which framework/dependencies you choose to use.

For a java-specific solution, you can utilize an **InputStream** as seen in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499306/how-to-read-application-properties-file-without-environment) posts.

If your project uses the Spring framework, you can utilize the [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation.

```
public class Config {
  private int param1;
  private boolean param2;
  private String param3;
  ...

  public Config(@Value("config.param1") int param1, 
                @Value("config.param2") boolean param2, 
                @Value("config.param3") String param3, 
  ) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
    this.param3 = param3;
    ...

  }
}
```